# no output in pycharm

Tags: python, vlc

This code works on IDLE but not on pycharm.

```
import vlc

prefix = "http://bendo:1q2w3e1q2w3eben90i@62.212.32.154:81/"
ip_address = "226.0.3.7:12345"

def play_stream(prefix, ip_address):
 vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()

player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
player.set_mrl(f"{prefix}{ip_address}")
player.play()


play_stream(prefix, ip_address)
```

P.S these are local ip-s,but i dont think it matters

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If i run this code in IDLE it does open a vlc window,but not on pycharm,it just returns:Process finished with exit code 0 and that's it,so I want to know that's the difference between pycharm and idle,or how should i get an output in pycharm